# Django-htmx: Understanding trigger_client_event from the django_htmx module

Tags: django, htmx

The other day someone suggested me to start using the django_htmx module to boost my htmx experience in the framework. One of the functionalities I'm more interested on is the trigger_client_event response modifier that seems to be able to trigger an event in the client.

Here's the code I'm using in the back-end and the client:

[customMixins.py]

```
    from django.views import View
    from django_htmx.http import retarget, reswap, trigger_client_event
    
    class HxFormValidationMixin(View):
        hx_retarget = 'this'
        hx_reswap = 'innerHTML'
        hx_event = ''
    
        def form_invalid(self, form):
            response = super().form_invalid(form)
            return reswap(retarget(response, self.hx_retarget), self.hx_reswap)
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            response = super().form_valid(form)
            return trigger_client_event(response, self.hx_event)
```

[views.py]

```
    ...
    class AAList(ListView):
        model = AssistantStudent
        template_name = 'AA/AlumnosAyudanteList.html'
        queryset = AssistantStudent.objects.all().order_by('as_group','as_name')
    
        #def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #    response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        #    return trigger_client_event(response, 'modalHide')

    class AAUpdate(HxFormValidationMixin, UpdateView):
        template_name = 'AA/AlumnoAyudanteForm.html'
        model = AssistantStudent
        form_class = AssistantStudentForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('list-alumnos-ayudante')
        hx_retarget = '#AAForm'
        hx_event = 'modalHide'
    ...
```

[script.js]

```
    ...
    $(document).on('modalHide', function(event) {
        $('#assistantStudentModal').modal('hide');
    });
    ...
```

[AlumnosAyudante.html]

```
    ...
    <table id="AAList" hx-trigger="load" hx-get="{% url 'list-alumnos-ayudante' %}" hx-target="this">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="assistantStudentModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="assistantStudentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" id="AAForm">
                {% include 'AA/AlumnoAyudanteForm.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

[AlumnoAyudanteForm.html]

```
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="assistantStudentModalLabel">{% if object %}Editar{% else %}Crear{% endif %} Alumno Ayudante</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form hx-post="{{targetURL}}" hx-target="#AAList" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_div}}
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

When the commented code in the views is un-commented the event is processed adequately. But this is just a patch since the 'modalHiden' event should trigger when the form is posted and validated.

I made a lot of debugging and checked that the pipeline is working correctly. The client is receiving the expected `Hx-Trigger:{'modalHide':{}}` header in the response to the form submitted POST-REQUEST. Yet the event is not being triggered. The only difference between the two cases (code commented and un-commented) is that one is a POST-REQUEST and the other is a GET-REQUEST.

[HERE](https://imgur.com/a/yq4oiv0) are pictures of the browser dev tools where you can see the headers of the POST-REQUEST and subsequent GET-REQUEST when the code is un-commented. Only the second case triggers the event.

Where lays the problem?

Comment: I have not tried using trigger_client_event in class based views but when doing it in my function i still need to return the response after including it as a parameter in my trigger_client_event. But this package is new to me as well and I am here trying to figure something out about params. It also seems like you are trying to call the client side function " instead of an actual function

Comment: I haven't used htmx with jquery so I'm not sure if that's the issue, but you can try catching the event on the body instead of document. Smth like: `document.body.addEventListener('modal-hide', function(evt) {})`

Comment: @twomed, I checked the response headers in my browser and I'm getting this:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2023 08:04:57 GMT

Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.5

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Location: /alumnosAyudante/list

HX-Trigger: {"modalHide": {}}

X-Frame-Options: DENY

Content-Length: 0

Vary: Cookie

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Referrer-Policy: same-origin

Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin`

Comment: @twomed the Hx-Trigger is being sent properly, I believe. Meaning the issue is probably in my client side code. I believe this because the rest of the pipeline is working fine withut spaming any kind of errors.

Comment: @mariodev, I tried:

`document.body.addEventListener('modalHide', function(){
    alert('I regret my life choices');
 });`

I removed the hyphen, just in case, but still is not triggering. As I said before, my problem is that the rest of the pipeline seems to be working perfectly, meaning the problem is in this endpoint. But nothing seems to work.

I had to use the following patch:

`$(document).on('htmx:afterSwap', function(event) {
if (event.target.id === 'AAList') {
    $('#assistantStudentModal').modal('hide');
}
});`

It does what I wanted, but is not what I wanted.

Comment: Are you running your javascript code inside the body tag?

Comment: @mariodev, the patch worked, and the rest of the javascript I'm using works as intended. The only thing that's failing it's that little piece of code.

Comment: @mariodev, I checked the event listeners in my browser dev tool and is listed there. The only thing I have left to try is starting a new project from scratch and trying to recreate the problem.

Comment: Yes, please. If you can specify what exactly is not working, given what you've tried so far, and how you want it to work. It would also be helpful, if you can provide complete code examples related to the issue, so it allows other people to recreate it on their own. Tx.

Comment: @mariodev, I updated the question. Now contains all the code involved in the pipeline and an updated problem. I have managed to trigger the hidenModal event using a different response (to a GET-REQUEST that is triggered right after the POST-REQUEST is successfull). This leaves me with a new question: Why is the event not being triggered with the POST-REQUEST response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is once the redirection is done, all htmx specific headers are cleared (they are not passed to another request), hence the htmx cannot process the response. It's "taken over" by the browser, which handles it as a normal django response.

When using `response = super().form_valid(form)`, it cause django to trigger redirect internally, due to how `UpdateView` works.

You need to return an html response, so instead of:

```
response = super().form_valid(form)
return trigger_client_event(response, self.hx_event)
```

you need to do:

```
response = render(
    self.request,
    "your_template.html",
    self.get_context_data(),
)
return trigger_client_event(response, self.hx_event)
```

HTMX will inject the rendered html in whatever target you've set for hx-post.

This shows why CBVs are a bad idea when using htmx, with FBVs it is more readable, you avoid all this overriding and it's easier to control the request/response flow.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since is the more reasonable approach. Tho I'm really tided to CBV in this one 'cause I have yet to repeat this process a dozen times and I need my code to be as reusable as possible. Probably I should just create some custom CBV so I can have more control of the request/response flow, as you said.

Comment: To increase the usefulness of the answer, if possible, add why the redirect prevents my client code from being able to process the response.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that all browser manage responses with 302 status transparently. Meaning AJAX and therefore HTMX can't handle these responses. That's why the event doesn't triggers on the POST-REQUEST response, as it is a redirect code-status: 302 response; but it triggers normally for a response with code-status: 200.

There is no way to capture a 302 status response that I'm aware and all the available solutions are workarounds.

Therefore I wrote a custom middleware to handle responses with status code 302 that contain a Hx-Trigger header. The middleware simply transfer the header to the next response it handles. It is not fool proof but it can be easily improved and generalized:

```
    class ResponseHxTriggerTranfer:
        def __init__(self, get_response):
            self.get_response = get_response
            self.storage = []
    
        def __call__(self, request):
            response = self.get_response(request)
            if self.storage:
                header = self.storage.pop()
                response[header[0]] = header[1]
            elif response.status_code == 302:
                if response.has_header('Hx-Trigger'):
                    self.storage.append(response.headers.pop('Hx-Trigger'))
            return response
```

With the middleware now the code worked as expected.

Comment: @mariodev, the problem is that is not possible to handle a 302 status response. Maybe I can workaround this issue creating a custom middleware. We'll see. I'm burned out, so for now I'll keep the patch. If you can find an elegant solution to my problem, you are very welcome.